# Minitube for Ubuntu 12.04 is outdated

Tags: 12.04, video, flash, vlc, minitube

The version of Minitube offered via the Ubuntu Software Center is very old. In fact, it doesn't even work anymore. I know Ubuntu 12.10+ offers a new version of the application, but I want to stick with the LTS version for stability and support reasons. My question therefore is:

- Who is the maintainer of the Minitube-Ubuntu package and how do I contact this person?
- How can I vote for an up to date version of Minitube for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Additional info: I know I could just [add a PPA](http://flavio.tordini.org/minitube/minitube-linux-setup) to my system, which will grant me access to the newest version of Minitube, but I don't trust this kind of procedure. Webupd8 might be a well known and trusted source, but it's not an option for me.

Comment: possible source of info on outdatedness reasons: http://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the Ubuntu packages site you'll find all the contact information you need.

[image]

Then below you search for the package you want info on.

[image]

After that you'll get the results of your query. Click on the distribution name to access it.

[image]

On the right side of the site you'll find the contact info for Ubuntu and for the Debian maintainer.

[image]

And finally,  as described in this question:

- [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

> Once the release happens additional changes to those packages only happen for bug fixing and security issues. There are no more upgrades done to the packages in the official repository even if new versions of the packages are released.

Comment: This answers only half their question.

Comment: @TheLordofTime So does your answer... :P

Comment: @Seth the point from my answer was that contacting the maintainer won't help them.  12.04's not getting an updated version, except MAYBE in backports, and only if someone goes and tests backporting.

Comment: First of all: Thank you - both of you. I didn't expect such detailed answers shortly after I posted my question. Excellent! @Uri & Seth: "changes to those packages only happen for bug fixing and security issues" <- Minitube 1.6 for Ubuntu 12.04 is bugged, because the version available to us via the Software Center is known not to work. This has been verified by Flavio, the creator of Minitube. Only versions 1.8+ work without issues - everything below that is bugged. My question therefore is: Is this "bug" sufficient to ask for an updated version? Ty

Comment: @Oranges10e I'd say that yes, but maybe because it doesn't affect security they might need to consider it.

Answer (score 1):

The versions in 12.04 are pretty much "locked' into place because it's an already-released stable Ubuntu version.

The only way to get a more updated version would be a PPA, building from source, WebUpd8, or a backported version, assuming there is one.

The other answer on this question by Uri Herrera will answer how to find out the maintainer.